# Do loop Implementation

Tags: programming, procedural-programming, infinite-loop

I want to generalise the following algorithm to a loop overall possible subsets of the original set.

the algorithm has the following form:
`ver={X41,X42,X43,X44}`
and
`ureg = Product[ver[[i]]^rho[i], {i, 1, 4}] B3^((d - 5)/2)`

`ureg` is a function that is defined somewhere else.

```
dlist=Table[FullSimplify[D[Log[ureg],ver[[i]]]],{i,1,4}]

dlistnew=dlist/.{s:>17,t:>23,m1:>37,m2:>43,d:>1/97,rho[1]:>1/113,rho[2]:>1/149,rho[3]:>1/173,rho[4]:>1/197}; 

EQSu=Table[dlistnew[[i]]==0,{i,1,4}];

SOL=Solve[EQSu,ver];

lenSOL=Length[SOL]
```

Here's what I have so far to generalise the algorithm to all possible subsets. After implementing, the changes suggested by user MarcoB The loop has now the following forms, and even so I don’t get any error messages it continues to evaluate without giving a result so what is the problem now

```
subsets = Subsets[ver];

Do[currentset = subsets[[k]];
 
 dlistdo = 
  Table[D[Log[ureg], currentset[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[currentset]}];
 
 EQSudo = Table[dlistdo == 0, {l, 1, Length[subsets]}];
 
 SOLdo = Solve[EQSudo, ver];
 
 lenSOLdo = Length[SOLdo];, {k, 2, Length[subsets]}]

{lenSOLdo, currentset}
```

If implemented without looking. However, I get error messages or only the length of the original set ver.

As I'm relatively new to Mathematica and it is my first time working with do loops, any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, you need to include all computation in your loop construct, separated by `;`. Since you know `Table`, though, an even better approach than loops would be to use that. A few more comments: 1) your `dlist` is equivalent to `dlist = D[Log[ureg], {ver}]`; I would avoid the `FullSimplify` that can be very time-consuming on symbolic expressions, since you are injecting numerical values anyway. 2) you don't need to set each equation equal to $0$ explicitly; you can just write `Solve[dlistnew == 0, ver]`. 3) avoid `Print`, just use `{lensol, currentset}` to return your results.

Comment: For further help you will need to include the definitions of all variables (`ureg`, `ver`, etc) so we can run your code.

Comment: I have implemented the changes you suggested, however, it now continues to validate without giving a result.